# Show element for a second, then hide it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show an element for a short amount of time, then hiding it with a CSS transition, on a button click.

Here's the outline of what I did.

1. `elem` has a property of `opacity: 0`.
2. Fire event when button gets selected.
3. The events function will add, then remove a class named `show` to `elem`.
4. CSS has the following property: `transition: opacity 500ms ease 1000ms;`.
5. `#elem.show` has a property of `opacity: 1`.

The problem is, nothing happens when the button gets clicked on. How can I make element get shown, without a transition effect, then, after `1s` close with a transition?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  elem.classList.add('show');
  elem.classList.remove('show');
});
```

```css
#elem {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease 1000ms;
}
#elem.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Press Me</button>
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: You need to remove the class after 1 second

Comment: you add/remove the class too quick ...

Comment: @Jessica:-use toggle...

Comment: what dark recesses of javascript has a `toggle` @DarshakGajjar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *setTimeout* is not *tidy* - it is better to listen to the [*`animation end event`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#Adding_the_animation_event_listeners) and remove the `show` class. I have also used `animation` to show and hide the element successively - see demo below:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  elem.classList.remove('show');
  // this force-restarts the CSS animation
  void elem.offsetWidth;
  elem.classList.add('show');
});

elem.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
  elem.classList.remove('show');
}, false);
```

```css
#elem {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
}
#elem.show {
  animation: anime 1s 1;
}
@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Press Me</button>
<div id="elem"></div>
```

---

#### Update

Listening to the *animation-end* event do not seem necessary actually - it works properly even without it. The gist here is the use of `void elem.offsetWidth` to *forcefully* restart the animation:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  elem.classList.remove('show');
  // this force-restarts the CSS animation
  void elem.offsetWidth;
  elem.classList.add('show');
});
```

```css
#elem {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
}
#elem.show {
  animation: anime 1s 1;
}
@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Press Me</button>
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: Why is using `setTimeout` not tidy?

Comment: Also, if you repeatedly click on the button, the elem will disappear. I don't want that behavior. I want it to stay for as long as you click the button, then 1 sec after that. (just like the accepted answer). But thanks for the answer!

Comment: Regarding why `setTimeout` is untidy - one is that when you would do this in real-life heavy pages where DOM loading times can come into play (especially if there is a lot of code inside your listener) it can happen that your css `animation duration` and `setTimemout` may not match perfectly (that's why a *callback* is preferred). Another reason is *just* that you have to take care to keep the  *same* seconds in CSS and JS which *may* cause troubles in real-life projects...

Comment: Just tried the demo, and repeatedly click on the button will not make the square stay.

Comment: @Jessica sorry, I'd made a mistake there, corrected the answer, thanks for the understanding! :)

Answer (score 2):

just do this :

```
 setTimeout(function() { elem.classList.remove('show'); }, 1000);
```

instead of writing :

```
elem.classList.remove('show');
```

To handle repeated clicks, do this ::

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
var timeOutFunc;

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  elem.classList.add('show');
  clearTimeout(timeOutFunc);
  timeOutFunc = setTimeout(function() {elem.classList.remove('show') } , 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought of that, but the problem is, if you repeatedly click on the button, it will not restart the timer. Is there a way to restart the timer after before calling it?

Comment: This should avoid repeated clicks issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this...i Hope its resolved your prblm

https://jsfiddle.net/b3en368p/5/

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    elem.classList.add('show');
     setTimeout(function(text){
        elem.classList.remove('show');
      }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: It should be `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2):

This borrows from other answers, and addresses the multiple press "issue"

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');

btn.addEventListener('click', (function() {
  var timer = null;
  return function() {
    elem.classList.add('show');
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = null;
    }
    timer = setTimeout(e => elem.classList.remove('show'), 1000);
  };
})());
```

```css
#elem {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease 500ms;
}

#elem.show {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Press Me</button>
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the purpose of `if (timer)` (I know it checks for null, but why do we have to?)

Comment: fair enough ... you can just clearTimeout regardless

Comment: Thanks. Gonna accept @binariedMe because he was first, but will up-vote your answer.

Comment: no probs - didn't see the edited version, just your concerns about it :p

Answer (score 0):

Add css

```
#elem {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
}

#elem.show {
    display: block;
}
```

Your listener should be like this-

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    elem.classList.add('show');
    setTimeout(function(){
        elem.classList.remove('show');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought of that, but the problem is, if you repeatedly click on the button, it will not restart the timer. Is there a way to restart the timer after before calling it?

Comment: @Jessica please look at this fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/sarang2009/bL37pL85/ does this what you expect?